# Remove <script> before execution

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to remove other `<script>` elements from body using **plain javascript**. The structure of the html page is:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
            for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++){
                alert(scripts[i].outerHTML)
                scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
            }
    </script>
    </head>
<body>

    ...

    <script type="text/javascript"> alert('script 1'); </script>

    ...

    <script type="text/javascript"> alert('script 2'); </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when the script inside `<head>` section is loaded is too late (`DOMContentLoaded`) and the `body` scripts are already in the queue for execution.

In this context, **using plain javascript**, how can I remove the `script` elements from the body before they get executed?

EDIT:

*Just to clarify, the `<body>` is not mine. It is an extraction from somewhere else.*

Comment: I would be pretty surprised if there were any reliable way of doing this even for `async` or `deferred` scripts, and for ordinary script tags as in your example I strongly suspect that it's impossible.

Comment: FWIW, this seems like a design flaw. What's the use case here?

Comment: You can't target that element with the dom api until it has been parsed. Once it has been parsed, it is too late to remove it because it has already been executed.

Comment: @esqew, this is not a design flaw. The scripts in `body` are not mine. The one in `head` is. This html body is a extraction from somewhere else.

Comment: If you're retrieving a document with `<script>` nodes from somewhere else, have you thought about parsing them out before inserting them into the DOM?

Comment: @esqew Yes I thought of it. Since you mentioned, how to remove the `<scripts>` tags of an html using `sed` command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable another script tag in javascript. Trying to remove the script elements with DOM manipulation won't work. However there are tricks to block a script execution in some circumstances.

#### 1.  Pass `application/json` as content-type

This will tell the browser to interpret the block as a json. It will only work if the content-type is present in the html, not if it is changed from some other js code.

```
<script type="application/json">console.log("Ignored")</script>
```

#### 2.  CSP headers

You can use the [Content security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src) header to only allow some sources for the scripts.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self'">
<script>console.log("This will be executed")</script>
<script src="www.external-site.com/this-will-be-blocked.js"></script>
```